# Панель лайков под Фотографией

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragment, android-layout

Подскажите, как сделать такую панельку снизу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит на макете
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так при на запущенном устройстве
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_best.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_bottom">
</include>
</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar_bottom.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_btm"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="90dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Разметку прикрепите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использование ViewPager во фрагменте ведёт ко вложенности фрагментов, что чревато большими проблемами.
2. Использование `RelativeLayout` во `fragment_best.xml` ничем не оправдано. Замените его на `LinearLayout` и проставьте вес для `ViewPager` равным `1`
3. Делать нижнюю панель через `Toolbar` - странная идея. Сделайте это также просто через `LinearLayout`

Вообще проблема может быть во многих местах, в т.ч. из-за `CoordinatorLayout`, коий может запутаться в таком обилии вложенных сущностей.

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно основная проблема крылась в `CoordinatorLayout`